# Batch transactions for MetaMask using sendAsync

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, metamask

I have MetaMask working nicely - it's so cool! However, I have a (react) form that gathers in lots of information and creates 14 distinct calls to `sendTransaction`. Hence, I (currently) get 14 popup windows from MetaMask, asking me to accept those transactions. In fact, exactly like this situation: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/1000

...which I see was 'solved'. So I know it's possible to batch requests, but my question is how? Basically, how should I form the `sendAsync` call? For instance, say I had these three transactions:

```
myContractObject.doSomething(name,type)
myContractObject.doSomethingElse(hash)
myContractObject.doSomethingElseEntirely(key)
```

What would my call to `web3.currentProvider.sendAsync` look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **[batch request](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#batch-requests)** web3 function.

```
var batch = web3.createBatch();
batch.add(myContractInstance.doSomething(arg1, arg2, {from: account, gas: 4000000}));
batch.add(myContractInstance.doSomethingElse(arg1, arg2, {from: account, gas: 4000000}));
batch.add(myContractInstance.doSomethingElseEntirely(arg1, arg2, {from: account, gas: 4000000}));
batch.execute();
```

Metamask asks the user for confirmation 3 times:[image]

Comment: But I think sendAsync will only ask for confirmation once....

Comment: This still opens multiple tabs on MetaMask.

Comment: Got it. I only see one tab but multiple confirmations are required for each transaction while it should be one confirmation!

Comment: @GregJeanmart - thanks - looks like your batch.add solution is correct - as soon as the bug is fixed (see below), I'll accept it as the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You've caught a legitimate bug in MetaMask, I've opened it on the MetaMask github repository (which is where we track bugs and close them), here:

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/1666

Comment: Excellent - thanks - I've also added a comment to the MetaMask issue...